# Practical assignments Hardware/Server projects

Tags: networks, hardware

Due to a teacher shortage I will have a class of "IT-Systems & Devices" students in a couple of weeks. The class should be group projects of 3 students in which they will have to do research (and interviews with me) to asses what the end goal of the project is and how they can get there.

And of course they will need to build that end goal. My personal background is in software development so I sadly don't know any projects they could do.

Does anyone know some possible assignments or a site where I could find some? Because the teacher who used to do this left none behind.

Subjects are in the area of:

- **Hardware setup/maintenance** (like setting up laptops/servers with
  specific software or integrating security camera's or sensors in to a network.)
- **Networking**(setting up a network including security and maintaining that network (Or things like a web/database server)

The difficulty is aimed at freshman college it-students.

Comment: Since they are freshmen, can you ask current sophomores or juniors who took the class in the past what was done?

Comment: @BenI. I actually did, but my predecessor kinda neglected the course entirely... the assignments he had were fully theoretical and didn't come close to what was promised to the students.

Comment: What kind of hardware can the school provide for the students to work with? That may be the biggest factor because if the answer is "none" or "we have all these workstations but you can't change anything" then it becomes all "virtual".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  don't have any insight in to the budget, but a few hundred euro's should be possible.

Comment: If it is a few hundred Euros per group of 3 students, then there is likely quite a bit you could do using Raspberry Pis or similar tiny machines + some IO devices/sensors/etc. Sounds interesting. Closest I had was as a junior (I think) where we got to use pairs of brand new IBM PC ATs to write our own bare-bones networking software with interprocess/networked message passing, etc. Those were the days...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact already got 4 pies with some sensors but well nothing i know of for them to do with them xD Also got some severs even :|